# Apache not serving subdomain images

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have "Apache 2.4.6 (Ubuntu)" and "PHP 5.5.4-1 (cli)" on my server and I have set up a subdomain which is working fine, running the PHP scripts, but none of the images are showing up. I have typed the URL of the image into a web browser and it just sits there loading for ages.

I have been playing around with my sites-available config files but can't seem to get them to show. I have no .htaccess files blocking the images or anything like that.

This is my subdomain.domain.com.conf file (edited to not give out any details):

```
# domain: subdomain.domain.com
# public: /home/username/public/domain.com/subdomain/public

<VirtualHost subdomain.domain.com:80>
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>

  <Directory "/home/username/public/domain.com/subdomain/public">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name), and any aliases
  ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
  ServerName  www.subdomain.domain.com
  ServerAlias subdomain.domain.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/username/public/domain.com/subdomain/public

  # Log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog  /home/username/public/domain.com/log/error.log
  CustomLog /home/username/public/domain.com/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I try to view:
    subdomain.domain.com/elements/img/test.png

the browser just sits their loading...

Am I looking in the right place to fix this? Should I be checking other config files? Does my domain.com.conf file mess with the subdomain one somehow?

Thanks, I appreciate all your help!

Comment: What is the apache's access log and error log?

Comment: access log has 1 line
119.63.196.28 - - [02/Oct/2013:06:12:56 +0000] "GET /images/mini.png HTTP/1.1" 404 473 "-" "Baiduspider-image+(+http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.htm)"

which isn't the image I am trying to access and the error log has:
[Thu Oct 03 13:02:44.627024 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24839] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Oct 03 13:02:45.838208 2013] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 24955] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.4-1+debphp.org~precise+1 configured -- resuming normal operations

Which is me doing apache restarts I believe...

Comment: Ok, I just entered the URL of an image that is in the main domain images folder and that shows up, I added the subdomain prefix to the URL thinking that would give me a 404 but its served me the image that is sat on my main domain?! How is that happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you do not use name based virtual hosting. Unless you have a separate ip for each host?

Try changing your virtual host to:

`<VirtualHost *:80>`

You might need to change your main host as well but it's all explained here in the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html).

Hope it help you forward.

Comment: Changed all my .conf files to have <VirtualHost *:80> but still the same... Should I put my main domain .conf file in the original post? Can that effect it?

Comment: Did a ctrl+F5 and the image came back! I am assuming it was the VirtualHost part that did the trick? I might change it back and see what happens.

Comment: If you do not have the correct virtual host setting, named vs ip based apache will not be able to tell them apart and you end up in the default site for all requests. Playing around with it is not a bad idea to understand it all. Good luck. :-)

Comment: I did have one *:80 and others domain.com:80 etc and it was redirecting to the site with *:80... so I get that part. I couldn't get the image to stop loading by changing it back again but whatever. All is working as expected now, though all this "Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews" confuses me, when I have a spare hour or so I am going to look into what each one means so I know exactly what my server will do on request. Thanks for your help btw, appreciated!

Comment: You should have all set to `*:80` and then `ServerName` will tell apache which host to use. Best is to do as you intend, to play around with it.